# How to set file path to the root of the current directory

Tags: c#, windows

I want to save my log file to the root of the current directory.

Right now my file path is 
"path": "%temp%\logs\log.txt"
this is working fine but I want to save it to the root of current directory.
For example say my app path is d:\SampleApp\Myapp and I want my log to save to d:\logs\log.txt
the drive 'd' might change on deployment. So want to make it relative of which ever drive is used.
I want to resolve this through appsettings.json, not through coding.
TIA

Comment: Just to  clarify.. I do not want to write or add any code to support this. Want to handle it through appsettings.json only.

Comment: Please, specify that on your question to get answered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To set your root folder where you can save a file, you need to have the direction without the root directory and then use the method `Combine()` from the `Path` class contained in `System.IO`.

> To get all the drives, you would make use of `DriveInfo` class
>   contained in `System.IO` namespace and their attribute `Name` to get
>   the root directory.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> using System.IO;
> ...
>
> ...
> DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
>
> foreach(DriveInfo x in allDrives)
> {
>     Console.WriteLine(x.Name);
> }
>
> // Console: "C:\"
> // Console: "D:\"
> ```

And then you can combine the root directory path with the file path as following:

```
Path.Combine(rootPath, filePathWithoutRoot);
```

To get the root directory of a path, you can use `GetPathRoot()` method from `Path` class that's contained in the namespace `System.IO`. This method returns to you the root directory from a path passed as `string` argument.

> **At this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getpathroot(v=vs.110).aspx) of Microsoft MSDN you can get more information and
>   this example of how to use it:**
>
> ```
> string path = @"\mydir\"; 
> string fileName = "myfile.ext"; 
> string fullPath = @"C:\mydir\myfile.ext"; 
> string pathRoot;
>
> pathRoot = Path.GetPathRoot(fullPath); Console.WriteLine("GetPathRoot('{0}') returns '{1}'", fullPath, pathRoot);
>
> // This code produces output similar to the following: 
> //
> // GetPathRoot('C:\mydir\myfile.ext') returns 'C:\'
> ```

**At this page from the Microsoft MSDN site you can get more information about it:**

[Path.GetPathRoot Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getpathroot(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I dont want to write code.. only want to change path in the appsettings.json

Answer (score 0):

Try this (using System.IO):

string root = Path.GetPathRoot(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
Also, You can use Path.GetFullPath() instead Path.GetPathRoot() and remove unwanted part from the string without hardcoding the folder name
And append your folder to it.